# Find vertex coordinates of a triangle with sides 6, 25, 29 in 3D

Tags: computational-geometry

An [Integer triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle) is a triangle all of whose side lengths are integers. I am trying to find coordinates of the vertices of triangle $OAB$ having side lengths 6, 25, 29. I suppose $O(0,0,0)$ and $A(6,0,0)$ and I tried to find the point $B$

```
o = {0, 0, 0};
a = {6, 0, 0};
b = {x, y, z};
b /. Solve[
       {
        SquaredEuclideanDistance[o, b] == 25^2, 
        SquaredEuclideanDistance[a, b] == 29^2,
        -50 <= x <= 100, -50 <= y <= 50, -50 <= z <= 50, x y z != 0
       }, {x, y, z}, Integers
     ]
```

> {{-15, -16, -12}, {-15, -16, 12}, {-15, -12, -16}, {-15, -12,
> 16}, {-15, 12, -16}, {-15, 12, 16}, {-15, 16, -12}, {-15, 16, 12}}

What is another way to find the coordinates of the vertices of a triangle having sides 6, 25, 29?

Comment: I always wonder when people have a working solution to their problem but want _another_ way of solving it. Why? Does this somehow not work? Is it too slow? Is the result wrong? Is the code too long?

Comment: At least he didn't require that the code be as efficient as absolutely possible.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but do the vertex coordinates need to be integers too? It does not seem to be a requirement, and yet it is the answer you expect. Don't we have infinitely many such triangles, even after fixing O and A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing special, just the conditions are redundant.

```
o = {0, 0, 0};
a = {6, 0, 0};
b = {x, y, z};
SolveValues[{Total[(o - b)^2] == 25^2, Total[(a - b)^2] == 29^2}, {x, y, z}, Integers]
Clear[o, a, b]
```

---

```
{{-15, -20, 0}, {-15, -16, -12}, {-15, -16, 12}, {-15, -12, -16},
{-15, -12, 16}, {-15, 0, -20}, {-15, 0, 20}, {-15, 12, -16},
{-15, 12, 16}, {-15, 16, -12}, {-15, 16, 12}, {-15, 20, 0}}
```

Comment: Can I add like this `{b} /.SolveValues`?

Comment: @Laurenso: Use the same code just with `Solve` instead of `SolveValues` like so - `b /.Solve`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, o, a, b]
o = {0, 0, 0}; a = {6, 0, 0}; b = {x, y, z};
SolveValues[
 {
  EuclideanDistance[o, b] == 25,
  EuclideanDistance[a, b] == 29
 }, {x, y, z}, Integers
]

(* Out: 
{{-15, -20, 0},  {-15, -16, -12}, {-15, -16, 12}, {-15, -12, -16},
 {-15, -12, 16}, {-15,   0, -20}, {-15,   0, 20}, {-15,  12, -16},
 {-15,  12, 16}, {-15,  16, -12}, {-15,  16, 12}, {-15,  20,   0}}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a brute-force solution.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lens[k_List] := 
 Partition[k, 2, 1, {2}] // Map[Apply[EuclideanDistance]]

o = {0, 0, 0};
a = {6, 0, 0};
cba1 = Flatten[#, 2] &@
   CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-22, 22}, {-22, 22}, {-22, 22}}, {1, 1, 
     1}];
p1 = cba1 // 
   Select[#, 
     EuclideanDistance[o, #] == 20 || 
       EuclideanDistance[a, #] == 29 &] &;
p2 = cba1 // 
   Select[#, 
     EuclideanDistance[o, #] == 29 || 
       EuclideanDistance[a, #] == 20 &] &;

g1 = (lens /@ ({o, a, #} & /@ p1) // 
    Position[#, _?(ContainsAll[{25, 6, 29}]), 1, Heads -> False] &) //
   Extract[p1, #] &
```

> {{-15, -20, 0}, {-15, -16, -12}, {-15, -16,    12}, {-15, -12, -16},
> {-15, -12, 16}, {-15, 0, -20}, {-15, 0,    20}, {-15, 12, -16}, {-15,
> 12, 16}, {-15, 16, -12}, {-15, 16,    12}, {-15, 20, 0}}

```
g2 = (lens /@ ({o, a, #} & /@ p2) // 
    Position[#, _?(ContainsAll[{25, 6, 29}]), 1, Heads -> False] &) //
   Extract[p2, #] &
```

> {{21, -20, 0}, {21, -16, -12}, {21, -16,    12}, {21, -12, -16}, {21,
> -12, 16}, {21, 0, -20}, {21, 0, 20}, {21,    12, -16}, {21, 12, 16}, {21, 16, -12}, {21, 16, 12}, {21, 20, 0}}

---

*Visualization:*

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]
   , Point@o, Point@a
   , Green, Point@g1
   , Blue, Point@g2
   , Dashed, Black,
   , InfiniteLine[{0, 0, 0}, #] & /@ {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
   
   }, Boxed -> True
  , Axes -> True
  , AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
  ]
 , RegionIntersection[Sphere[o, 25], Sphere[a, 29]] // 
  Region[#, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True] &
 , RegionIntersection[Sphere[o, 29], Sphere[a, 25]] // 
  Region[#, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True] &
 ]
```

---

*Explanation:*

The `Red` points are the ones given as `o` and `a`. To find the compliant integer triangles in 3D space, a `CoordinateBoundsArray` is generated using a step of `1` along each basis direction. `p1` and `p2` are points that are either `20` or `29` away from each of the given two points. A function `lens` finds all points (`g1` and `g2` shown in `Green` and `Blue` respectively) from these shortened lists such that the three required side lengths are present. This is done using `ContainsAll`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
b /. FindInstance[Norm[b] == 25 && Norm[b - a] == 29, b, Integers, 12]
```